# How to crawl SharePoint wiki page whose content changes based on query string parameters?

Tags: 2010, search, crawling

In a Team Site, I have a Wiki Page containing webparts whose content changes based on query string parameters. There are about 250 different parameter combinations.

How can I tell SharePoint to crawl the page using different querystring parameters in order to index all the available content?

If possible, I'd like to be able to alter the URLs without needing Central Admin access. Can a Links list in a site accomplish this, if I have one list item per different URL? Is SharePoint smart enough to follow the links since they point to a SharePoint page?

(Why am I using this approach, you ask? I'm trying to avoid having 250 different pages to maintain.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may have fewer pages to maintain, but what about version control? Workflow? Permissions? etc? This strategy seems to defeat the purpose of using SharePoint...

Comment: I should have included this originally: The page was meant to display data from a SharePoint list, but I wanted search results to only show these pages, not the source list itself. The content would be edited in the source list, all items by the same group of people.

Answer (score 1):

This can be specified by creating a custom [Crawl Rule](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792871%28v=office.14%29.aspx) in your Search Service Application.  Create the new rule using the path to you WIKI as the inclusion path and then be sure to check the "Crawl Complex URLs" option.

That said, you will still need some source to tell it which wiki URLs to crawl with what parameters.  Usually an index page will do this but I have also seen people create a dedicated landing page with all of the various combinations listed there.  If that is what you end up doing, you will also need to create a special Crawl Rule for just this page as well that has the "Follow links on the URL without crawling the URL itself" selected.  Otherwise, your index page will show up at the top of a LOT of search results!

Answer (score 0):

Does SharePoint even crawl the content within web parts on a page?  It will crawl the Page Content and also the content in a Content Editor web part but I am doubtful of others.

Comment: Good question. I'm going to mock-up your and Dave Wise's suggestions to see what really happens.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. I mocked this up, and no matter how I presented the data in the Wiki page, SharePoint would only crawl the page as if it had no query string parameters.